# How to ask a method to repeat itself from another method

Tags: c#

I need Method1 to repeat itself in the Method3. How can i do that? 
Code example [edit1]:

```
namespace NamespaceName
{
   public partial class ClassName
   {
       private void Method1(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          Statement1;
          Statement2;
          Statement3;
       }

       public void Method2 (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)

       {
          //Another bunch of statements
       }

       private void Method3 (object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
          "Want to repeat those statements from Method1 without copying them here"
       }
   }
}
```

P.S. I'm new to programming and i have no idea what my options are and searching the web didn't helped much either. 
Sorry if this question has already been asked and if so, could you please link it here? 
 
Edit1: Well, in attempt to write an abstract example instead of my actual code i omitted the important things. Now it should look more adequate.

Comment: You can call other methods: `public void Method3() { Method1(); }` - I'm not sure if this is what you're actually asking though.

Comment: You mean you want to call `Method1`?  Like, `Method1();` ?  It's not really clear where you're stuck.  Maybe you're just at the very beginning of a C# tutorial and need to keep going?  (Note also that pseudo-code tends to get only pseudo-answers.)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Tell me if it is not what you are looking for.

You need only call your method Method1 in your Method3.

```
   private Method3
   {
      //"Want to repeat those statements from Method1 without copying them here"
      //For your sender parameter, assuming that was a button named btn1.
      //you can send the btn1 as sender and null as eventargs.
      Method1(btn1, null); //Will execute the code in your method1.
   }
```

Comment: It kind of is but i messed up my original code example so it wasn't showing the important parts (sorry for that). I've edited it and also tried your solution. Unfortunately it doesn't work because of the "sender" parameter.